# Spring Boot Application Null ModelAndView returned

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have developed a spring boot (1.5.1.RELEASE) application using Java 1.8. I am using spring security with a custom user details services.

On successful authentication my application is not displaying the correct html page/view, it remains at the login page - this is what I see in the logs:

```
2017-12-15 23:19:43.998 DEBUG 10340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-12-15 23:19:43.998 DEBUG 10340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

This is something that I have done many times before but for some reason this time it isn't working and I can't figure out why, so I'm looking for some help.

This is my security config class:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

/** The Constant LOGIN_PAGE. */
private static final String LOGIN_PAGE = "/login";

/** The Constant AUTHORISED_REQUESTS_ANT_MATCHER. */
private static final String AUTHORISED_REQUESTS_ANT_MATCHER = "/**";

/** The Constant BAD_CREDENTIALS_EXCEPTION_URL. */
private static final String BAD_CREDENTIALS_EXCEPTION_URL = "/login?error";

/** The Constant ACCOUNT_EXPIRED_EXCEPTION_URL. */
private static final String ACCOUNT_EXPIRED_EXCEPTION_URL = "/login?accountexpired";

/** The Constant CREDENTIALS_EXPIRED_EXCEPTION_URL. */
private static final String CREDENTIALS_EXPIRED_EXCEPTION_URL = "/login?credentialsexpired";

/** The Constant ACCOUNT_DISABLED_EXCEPTION_URL. */
private static final String ACCOUNT_DISABLED_EXCEPTION_URL = "/login?accountdisabled";

/** The Constant ACCOUNT_LOCKED_EXCEPTION_URL. */
private static final String ACCOUNT_LOCKED_EXCEPTION_URL = "/login?accountlocked";

/** The find user by username command. */
@Autowired
private Command<FindUserByUsernameResp, FindUserByUsernameParam> findUserByUsernameCommand;

public SecurityConfig() {
    super();
}

// ===========================================
// Public Methods
// ===========================================

public Command<FindUserByUsernameResp, FindUserByUsernameParam> getFindUserByUsernameCommand() {
    return findUserByUsernameCommand;
}

public void setFindUserByUsernameCommand(Command<FindUserByUsernameResp, FindUserByUsernameParam> findUserByUsernameCommand) {
    this.findUserByUsernameCommand = findUserByUsernameCommand;
}

@Bean
public ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
    Map<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mappings.put(BadCredentialsException.class.getCanonicalName(), BAD_CREDENTIALS_EXCEPTION_URL);
    mappings.put(AccountExpiredException.class.getCanonicalName(), ACCOUNT_EXPIRED_EXCEPTION_URL);
    mappings.put(CredentialsExpiredException.class.getCanonicalName(), CREDENTIALS_EXPIRED_EXCEPTION_URL);
    mappings.put(DisabledException.class.getCanonicalName(), ACCOUNT_DISABLED_EXCEPTION_URL);
    mappings.put(LockedException.class.getCanonicalName(), ACCOUNT_LOCKED_EXCEPTION_URL);

    ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler = new ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
    return exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(new UserDetailsServiceImpl(getFindUserByUsernameCommand()));//.passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin().loginPage(LOGIN_PAGE).successForwardUrl("/")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(LOGIN_PAGE).permitAll()
        .antMatchers(AUTHORISED_REQUESTS_ANT_MATCHER).authenticated();
}


}
```

And this is my web configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

// ===========================================
// Public Members
// ===========================================

// ===========================================
// Private Members
// ===========================================

/** The Constant ROOT_URL. */
private static final String ROOT_URL = "/";

/** The Constant ROOT_VIEW. */
private static final String ROOT_VIEW = "app/views/index";

/** The Constant LOGIN_URL. */
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";

/** The Constant LOGIN_VIEW. */
private static final String LOGIN_VIEW = "login";

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 *
 * @see
 * org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
 * #addViewControllers(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.
 * ViewControllerRegistry)
 */
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController(ROOT_URL).setViewName(ROOT_VIEW);
    registry.addViewController(LOGIN_URL).setViewName(LOGIN_VIEW);
}

}
```

I have two html pages in my application, under the templates folder, and they are:

login.html (which displays fine)
app/views/index.html

My index.html file never gets displayed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try replacing your `ROOT_VIEW` to `/app/views/index`? Just add a slash  to begining.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem was an error in my thymeleaf markup. It took me a while to discover this as there was no evidence of an error in my logs.